# Combining graphs using Statsd & Graphite

Tags: metrics, graphing, graphite

In Statsd client, how do I combine two graphs to show it as a single one? 
[image]

Like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm just playing around with graphite and statsd right now, so I am no expert, but I might be missing something here...why would you combine it in statsd?  It seems you would want it to be combined in the Graphite UI, which will let you combine multiple stats onto a single graph.  In fact, I think you could create a graph with both of these metrics present and then save the graph to "My Graphs" to pull up later.

As far as statsd is concerned, you are just writing out two separate metrics, one being a counter called NumWarnings and another called Deployed. To get a graph like the one above, I supposed you'd need to assign an arbitrary value to Deployed as a counter for each deployment (100 seems like a good number).

Comment: One note on my answer above regarding how to graph "deployment"...see this great blog post from Mike Brittain of etsy: http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2010/12/08/track-every-release/

Comment: Thanks whabib. Do you know how to combine this in graphite?

Comment: It is relatively straightforward in the Graphite UI.  As you expand the tree of metrics on the left side of the screen, every individual metric you click on will be added to the graph. You can add as many as you wish, or remove individual ones using the widgets on the graph itself.  Once you have a graph that has all the metrics you want on it, save it (but you'll need to login first).

Comment: This is also a great resource now:
http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/whisper.html

Answer (score 0):

For people discovering this later: with graphite if you drag a graph with the mouse and hold it over another one for a few seconds, a green box will appear saying "Drop to Merge". Drop the graph when that appears and it will merge the two graphs into one.